# https showing error ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, redirect, amazon-ec2, https

I have setup ssl successfully
Im having trouble redirecting http requests to https
I tried : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/
from aws docs and didnt work.

i tried one of the SA answers and added

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.onepercent.club
 Redirect / https://www.onepercent.club/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.onepercent.club
</VirtualHost>
```

I added this code in the httpd.conf file in **/etc/httpd/conf**
Now the requests to http are redirected to https but showing error saying ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
Please help me resolve this error

SSL Certificate is setup perfectly and used to work when i manually type in https. Im having trouble only with redirecting.
Im hosting it on AWS EC2 t2.micro and my SSL is from GoDaddy

**EDIT**

SSL.conf

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
 ServerName www.onepercent.club
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile SOMEPATH
 SSLCertificateKeyFile SOMEPATH
 SSLCertificateChainFile SOMEPATH
</VirtualHost>
```

httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.onepercent.club
 Redirect / https://www.onepercent.club/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If you are using ELB, can you setup the ssl at the load balancer level and terminate the SSL at the load balance. the instances will always recieve the request as http. is there are special reason why you want to terminate the ssl at the instance level

Comment: I tried for hours with the load balance and idk what the problem is, im not able to attach the load balance to the instance. Thats the reason im trying to achieve this using code @ArunK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` is because you are trying to connect on the HTTPS port (443) using HTTPS. However your host is listening on 443 as a standard HTTP request.

To fix this your vhost should be configured to run SSL.

This can be done by adding the minimum [SSL configuration](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html) to the host a shown below.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.onepercent.club

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/www.example.com.cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/www.example.com.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This would sit in the vhost of your https domain (the one listening on port 443).

Comment: I already have this code. It contains path to certificate file, private key and chain

Comment: Have you got the full VHOST (blank out sensitive information)

Comment: Hmm this looks correct, testing does not seem to perform the redirect you mentioned. Did you disable this?

Comment: How could i have disabled it? Like any part in the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219038/discussion-between-chris-williams-and-prateek-bb).